no query error while trying to fecth data from Sanity
Working on a react native project, I m trying to fetch data from sanity, but I get this error 'no query', I double checked the projectId, the dataset name, I tried the query in the vision section of sanity studio and it works, the dataset is public.
Sanity.js
import { createClient } from "@sanity/client";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

const client = createClient({
    projectId: '18drtz8q',
    dataset: 'production',
    useCdn: true,
    apiVersion: 'v2022-07-03',
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);

export const getCategory = async () => {
    const items = await client.fetch('*[_type == "category"]').then((data) => {
        return data;
    });

    return items;
};

sanity.cli.js

import {defineCliConfig} from 'sanity/cli'

export default defineCliConfig({
  api: {
    projectId: '18drtz8q',
    dataset: 'production',
  }
})

Where I m trying to call the function to fetch data
const CategoryList = () => {

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setisLoading(true)
        getCategory()
            .then((data) => setCategories(data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        setTimeout(() => setisLoading(false), 2000)
    }, []);
...

I tried the same logic with react expo, and I was expecting the same results working with react native CLI
